# Disk space usage per owner, group or user

Tags: linux, disk-space, centos-7, df

I am writing a small tool in which I need to find per-user, owner or group File-system-memory-usage.

There is no quotas for each one, so all of them works under the same HDFS parameters in the cluster. I can get the total usage of this, but now im trying to filter only per user, group or owner files.

I only need the total for each one, we have araoung 40 users.

User 1 - Usage
User 2 - Usage
User 3 - Usage . . .

If there is a sintax that i can use with du or df, please let me know.

CENTOS 7 SO

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have the shared directory where all users can store contents. If that's the case, you can simple use 'du -csh /path/to/the/home/directory/of-particular-user'

Check this thread for per-user memory usage:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214315/how-to-find-user-memory-usage-in-linux